# Workarounds for virtual\non-virtual overloads

Tags: c++

A question that bothers my intern (and in return he bothers me, by inheritance).
A classic pitfall with overloading is an attempt to overload a virtual function with non-virtual counterpart. It's kind of counter-intuitive that  non-virtual variant stops being visible in derived class.

Let's say we have base class for serialization. Our intent is introduce a finalized wrapper `int readFrom(Arg &a)` for existing virtual function `int readFrom(int)`.

```
// raw packet structure
struct Arg { int a; };

// interface
struct PacketIO {
    int readFrom(Arg &a) { return readFrom(a.a); }
    // can rename this into something else, I vote for this.
    // "readFromRaw"
    virtual int readFrom(int) = 0;
};

// wrapper, some identification things may happen here
template<class OutT>
struct PacketWrapper : public PacketIO {
    using DataType = OutT;

    DataType& data() { return pak; }

private:
    DataType pak;
};
```

That interface is inherited by multiple classes PacketX.

```
// internal structure
struct  Dt { int d; };

// concrete type
struct PacketX : public PacketWrapper<Dt> {
    // that's what needed for resolution to happen, 
    // but it's a bad idea(tm), because of plural PacketX's sister-classes.

    // using PacketIO::readFrom;

    int readFrom(int a) override {  data().d = a; return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    PacketX x;
    Arg arg {42};
    x.readFrom(arg); // doesn't compile
    
    // Access via base class always works.
    static_cast<PacketIO*>(&x)->readFrom(arg); // works!
}
```

Why this happen, was described before, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22792864/overloaded-functionsvirtual-non-virtual)

Ultimately I know only four paths to solve the issue, i.e.

- Do not overload API function, which changes API.
- Do not access API via derived class.
- Make overload virtual too and expect someone to override it.
- Import function name into derived class's scope, which is prone to
  errors.

Did I miss something, provided an infrastructure like one above is already in place?

Comment: "non-virtual variant stops being accessible " -- that's not the case. Its name isn't found when you make an unqualified call, but it's still accessible. Why is importing the function name into the derived class's scope "prone to errors"? That's exactly the right approach here.

Comment: Incidentally, `virtual` has nothing to do with this. You'd run into the same issue if the base class had two non-virtual functions named `readFrom`.

Comment: You can also explicitly access `PacketIO::readFrom(Arg&)` in the derived class if you don't want to import the name with a using directive.

Comment: @PeteBecker Two non-virtual wouldn't make sense, at least in this case. Yeah that's approach mostly because that's boiler code  an intern can forget (and didn't knew because no education course covers that feature of `using` at all), Coincidentally, most IDEs (IDEA, VisualStudio, Qt) claim it is inaccessible because their name lookup is even worse than compiler's.

Comment: @chrysante ok, that's one I've been missing. Yeah, it's an unusual syntax to scare ladies off but that works

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie -- the point is that **virtual** isn't the problem; the problem is simply that the same name is defined in the base class and in the derived class, and the one in the derived class hides the one in the base class.

Comment: @PeteBecker no argument there

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie -- accessibility is specified by `public`, `protected`, and `private`. That doesn't change when a name is added to a derived class. That may be a bit too technical for this discussion, but the issue is not accessibility; it's just name lookup rules.